# Convert timestamp in Hive

Tags: timestamp, hive

My hive table currently has timestamp in this format `2015/02/13 22:36:25.000` as string.

How can I parse it as timestamp in "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss" format `2015-02-13 22:36:25`?

Comment: May be a starter: [Convert timestamp with timezone in Hive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25067674/convert-timestamp-with-timezone-in-hive?rq=1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way to do this is to convert it to a `BIGINT` and back again:

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(your_date_field, "yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS"))
FROM your_table;
```